# Changing an object's position without changing its position visually

Tags: three.js, geometry, position

[image]I have an instance of *Object3D* and visually it's at (0, 0, 0) but its actual position is shifted (and positions of this object's internals are shifted as well). So, basically geometry of this object is shifted in such a way that it compensates for position shift. So, I want to keep it visuallyy at (0, 0, 0) and change its position to (0, 0, 0).

In simple words, I want to shift object's position vector to this object's geometry position.
How can I do it?

Comment: Hard to discern what you're explaining without visualizing it, but does this help? https://discourse.threejs.org/t/understanding-loaded-obj-group-position/14407/4?u=marquizzo

Comment: @Marquizzo I see what you meant there and I have a small question about these two lines: 
`var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(car);
cube.position.copy(box.getCenter());`
will the second line shift the object in space or not? because it feels like it will shift the object in space, not compensate for the difference between _geometry's center vector_ and _position vector_

Comment: Yes, that would shift the position. If you want to keep the position at the origin, maybe you'd like to shift the `geometry` itself, which practically changes all vertex positions in a one-time operation (not good for animating). Have you looked at [`BufferGeometry.translate()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.translate)? You could translate the vertices by the opposite value you get from `box.getCenter()`.

Comment: @annwhoorma If you know where your object's actual center is, then negate this vector, use it to translate geometry's vertices, then set object's position to (0, 0, 0)

Comment: @Marquizzo I see what you meant about geometry. And yes, I use _.translate()_ to move geometry at first but then it happens that the object's position is connected to its geometry center and not to its geometry bottom. It happens so because for some objects it's an original property. So, in this case, I need to shift geometry up by half of the height of box3 and then shift position down to (0,0,0)?

Comment: Shifting the geometry by half the height works... Sounds like you're getting closer to the solution!

Comment: It also seems like _.translateY()_ shifts an object along with its position...

Comment: @Marquizzo I attached an image, maybe it will help :c